# ConnectionStrings in ASP .NET Core 2.0 with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm a beginner developer ASP.NET. Now I'm trying to connect to MSSQL server by using Entity FrameWorkCore.
But when I create migrations, it's worked. But the problem is I don't see any database in Microsoft SQL server.

I'm using VS Code and dotnet CLI to development.

MSSQL server 2014 Express.

My connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=vega; user id=sa; password=123456;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

},

And my Configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<VegaDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Now, I wanna see that database name "vega" display in Microsoft SQL Server.

Please help me!!

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you explain what you are trying to do or what isn't happening the way you want it?

Comment: Did you open the management studio? If you can't see the database, then under (your server Name) -> Databases. Right click and refresh.

Comment: Hi Sean Lange.

I create table thought EntityFrameWorkCore.
My problem is I dont see my database in MS SQL server after I create migrations.

Comment: Are you connected to your local SQLExpress instance? What happens if you run select * from sys.databases. Not really sure what you mean by "don't see my database".

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah. I don't see my database in MS SQL after I created migrations success. I think my connectionStrings is incorrect

Comment: OK so what is the question then?

Comment: your connectionstring is correct. Just his question is, Why don't him see the db created via SQL management studio

Comment: @NguyễnPhươngThuận connect to your SQL Express, try with sa account (with your connection string password), then do you see that db?

Comment: @Shuvra I did refreshed, still not display. I check by command dotnet ef database drop but notification is database "vega" not exists. That's the database has not been created.

Comment: just use code first approach, and create a table, see whether can you see the db. Without table configuration, i think entity core will not create and db, yet.

Comment: Are you sure the migration ran successfully? Have you enabled all logging?

Comment: @Jacky yea i dont see my database in MS SQL Server Management Studio. 
I try to drop database by dotnet cli but database has not been created

Comment: @Tubs Yeah I see all logging that Migrations successfully. Absolutely!


info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\PhuongThuan\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'VegaDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'

Comment: Can you go in the location of you database server: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ and find Vega.mdf file?

Comment: @SeanLange The question is why i dont see my database in MSSQL server management studio? What was I doing wrong?

Comment: @Shuvra Yeah. I did but I don't see that

Comment: When you opened the database in Sql Management Studio what did you put in for the server name?

Comment: If you can't see any  Vega.mdf then database is not created.

Comment: @Shuvra Yeah, I was fixed that. That is my connectionStrings incorrect.
Should be

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vega;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }